# How to edit posted data using Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a posted json data form record and i want to edit that form onclick, 
I am not able to populate my old data in the form to edit it.

```
<button style="margin:3px;" ng-click="put1(student)" onclick="opendiv();">Edit</button>
```

Here, student is an array and opendiv is to open model dialogue box.

```
self.put1 = function(student){
var studentname = student.name;
        var studentid = student.id;
        var studenttype = student.type;

var data = { studentname : self.newstudent.name,
studentid = self.newstudent.id ,
studenttype =self.newstudent.type
}
$http.put('/rest/student',data)
    .success(function(data){
        alert("updated");   })
    .error(function(errResponse) {
        console.error('Error while fetching notes');
});
};
```

Comment: remove onclick and call opendiv() in success() function with returned data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with old data when you say: 
   "I am not able to populate my old data"?!
If you are referring student's data as old data, be sure you have bind the students's data correctly to your input elements of your form, using ng-model directive, if you want to use AngularJS.

My advice is:

1. Use $scope, or $rootScope directive to save your student's data on the angular controller like "$scope.student".
2. Use ng-model directive to display your students list on the view like this

`<form name="studentForm"> 
       <input type="text" ng-model="student.name"/> 
       <button ng-click="edit();">Edit</button>
     </form>`
. 
 **ng-model="student.name"** will show you the old student's name, so you can edit it.

3. In angular controller implement your edit() function. like this

   `$scope.edit = function(){
          var data = $scope.student; /*the student's name is automatically updated   because of two-way data-binding*/
         $http.put('/rest/student',data)
           .success(function(data){
             alert("updated");  })
           .error(function(errResponse) {
           console.error('Error while fetching notes');
        });
      }`